# Fubini's Theorem Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, proof-verification

I've been working on Fubini's theorem proof, but there is something wrong with my proof since I have weaker assumptions.

Let $f,g:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)<\infty$ and $\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)<\infty$. Then, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[f(1)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)+...+f(N)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[f(1)\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M g(m)+...+f(N)\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M f(1)g(m)+...+\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M f(N)g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sum_{m=1}^M f(1)g(m)+...+\sum_{m=1}^M f(N)g(m)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{m=1}^M f(n)g(m)\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^N\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^M f(n)g(m)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(n) g(m)
\end{align*}
But, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m)\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$, we have that:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(n) g(m)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) g(m)
\end{align*}